# How to add custom fields to WooCommerce product data panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom **product type** for events in WooCommerce. Now I want to add some custom fields to it.

This can be achieved with functions like **woocommerce_wp_select()**, **woocommerce_wp_text_input()** etc. However, as far as I know, whith these function you can only add text input fields, textarea's, select boxes and select dropdowns.

I want to add a **date picker field**, a **file upload field** and an **url input field**.

I have created these fields and they do **render on the admin panel as they should**, but **the values are not saved** (although I'm using the action hook 'woocommerce_process_product_meta'). Only **the first 2 fields** (event_type and event_location), which are created with the WooCommerce function, are stored properly.

What am I doing wrong here?

My code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'okappi_add_custom_fields');

function okappi_add_custom_fields()
{ ?>
<div id="event_details" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel hidden">

    <div class="options_group" class="show_if_event">
        <? woocommerce_wp_select([
            'id' => 'event_type',
            'label' => __('Event type', 'custom'),
            'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_event',
            'value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_type', true),
            'options' => array('online' => 'Online', 'international' => 'International', 'internal' => 'Internal'),

        ]); ?>

        <? woocommerce_wp_text_input([
            'id' => 'event_location',
            'label' => __('Event location', 'custom'),
            'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_event',
            'value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_location', true),
        ]); ?>

        <p class="show_if_event form-field event_start_date_field">
            <label for="event_start_date">Start date</label>
            <input type="date" id="event_start_date" name="event_start_date" class="date short">
        </p>

        <p class="show_if_event form-field event_end_date_field">
            <label for="event_end_date">End date</label>
            <input type="date" id="event_end_date" name="event_end_date" class="date short">
        </p>

        <p class="show_if_event form-field event_pdf_field">
            <label for="event_pdf">PDF upload</label>
            <input type="file" id="event_pdf" name="event_pdf" class="date short">
        </p>

        <p class="show_if_event form-field event_link_field">
            <label for="event_link">Event link</label>
            <input type="url" id="event_link" name="event_link" class="date short" placeholder="https://www.my-event.com/">
        </p>
    </div>

</div>'
<? }

add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_fields');

function save_custom_fields($post_id)
{
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

    $event_type = isset($_POST['event_type']) ? $_POST['event_type'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data('event_type', sanitize_text_field($event_type));

    $event_location = isset($_POST['event_location']) ? $_POST['event_location'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data('event_location', sanitize_text_field($event_location));

    $event_start_date = isset($_POST['event_start_date']) ? $_POST['event_start_date'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data('event_start_date', sanitize_text_field($event_start_date));

    $event_end_date = isset($_POST['event_end_date']) ? $_POST['event_end_date'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data('event_end_date', sanitize_text_field($event_end_date));

    $event_pdf = isset($_POST['event_pdf']) ? $_POST['event_pdf'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data('event_pdf', sanitize_text_field($event_pdf));

    $event_link = isset($_POST['event_link']) ? $_POST['event_link'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data('event_link', sanitize_text_field($event_link));

    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Note: to save fields you can use the `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object` hook, opposite the outdated `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook. 
Is it possible to add to your question, the full code you use to save.

Comment: @7uc1f3r I've added the code to save the values.

Comment: Your code contains some minor bugs that can be fixed very easily. However, I see that you also want to add an upload field and that is another story. Very little information can be found about this and therefore had to be written completely custom. Moreover, it must above all be safe.. for example [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69868316/11987538) contains some information about upload fields in the backend

Comment: Ok thanks @7uc1f3r, I will have a look at it.