# How to Add Custom Image Field to WooCommerce Product Creation Panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add a field to select/delete a picture for a product. The field must be done by code, without using a plugin. How can i do this?
Now I have added a text field and I am saving it. How to add a custom field for an image?

```js
// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');
// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_text_field',
            'placeholder' => 'Custom Product Text Field',
            'label' => __('Custom Product Text Field', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';

}

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id)
{
    // Custom Product Text Field
    $woocommerce_custom_product_text_field = $_POST['_custom_product_text_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_text_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field));

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69868316/13378498

Comment: I tried to add this code, but I didn't get an image field

Comment: The code is for variations but is a good example how to implement it.